# Basic C++ CSV class to read and write to .csv files

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, csv

I've been working through the fifth edition of Lajoie's C++ Primer and decided to write a CSV reader/writer as my first project. Its main features are:

- Able to explicitly call for:

  - Individual/multiple rows by index and range
  - Individual/multiple columns by name and index
- Able to write new rows using a `map<string,string>` formatted `<column, value>`.

The code is available on [Github](https://github.com/slin63/C-CSV) and pasted below. Call me out for poor practices, bad design choices, whatever itches you. It's my first dive into C++ and I want to know how to improve.

## `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "CSVFile.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string file_name = "Sample.csv";
    CSVFile csv_obj(file_name);

    typedef vector<vector<string>> CsvVector;

    vector<string> headers = csv_obj.get_header(); // Get available headers in passed CSV

    CsvVector column_one = csv_obj.get_column("Column 1");
    vector<string> row_1 = csv_obj.get_row(1); // Get rows by index
    CsvVector row_1_to_3 = csv_obj.get_row(0, 3); // Get rows by range

    map<string,string> row_map; // Map formatted Column: Column value
    row_map["Column 1"] = "ColumnOneVal";
    row_map["Column 2"] = "ColumnTwoVal";
    row_map["Column 3"] = "ColumnThreeVal";
    cout << endl;
    csv_obj.write_row(row_map); // Use row_map to write a new row

    return 0;
}
```

## `CSVFile.hpp`

```
#ifndef CSVFile_hpp
#define CSVFile_hpp

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

;class CSVFile {

typedef vector<vector<string>> CsvVector;
friend ostream& print(ostream&, const CSVFile&);

public:
    CSVFile() = default;
    CSVFile(const string&);

    inline vector<string>::size_type get_size();
    inline void headers();
    inline vector<string> get_header();

    CsvVector get_column(const int&);
    CsvVector get_column(const vector<int>&);
    CsvVector get_column(const string&);
    CsvVector get_column(const vector<string>&);

    vector<string> get_row(const int&);
    CsvVector get_row(const int&, const int&); // Rows in range

    // Planned: Explicitly declare line to write to.
    // Pass vector of strings to write lines for
    void write_row(const map<string,string>&);
    inline CsvVector rows();

private:
    vector<string> header;
    CsvVector contents;
    ifstream stream_read;
    ofstream stream_write;
    inline string remove_extension(const string&);
    vector<string> column_info(const string&);
    string merge_row_vector(const vector<string>&);
    int index_from_string(const string&);
    map<int,string> index_from_string(const map<string,string>& row_map);
};

ostream& print(ostream&, const CSVFile&);

void CSVFile::headers() {
    for (auto&& i : header)
        cout << i << ", ";
}

vector<string>::size_type CSVFile::get_size() {
    return contents.size();
}

string CSVFile::remove_extension(const string& s) {
    string ret = s;
    ret.erase(ret.find_last_of("."), string::npos);
    return ret;
}

vector<string> CSVFile::get_header() {
    return header;
}


CSVFile::CsvVector CSVFile::rows() {
    return contents;
}
#endif /* CSVFile_hpp */
```

## `CSVFile.cpp`

```
#include "CSVFile.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>

// file doc: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/
// stream_readtream constructor: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/17771/#msg89650
CSVFile::CSVFile(const string& file_name) {
    stream_read.open(file_name, ios::binary);
    string out_file = remove_extension(file_name) + "_OUT.csv";
    stream_write.open(out_file, ios::binary);
    stream_write << stream_read.rdbuf(); // Copy read file into output file
    bool line_is_header = true; // First line assumed to be the header
    stream_read.seekg(0); // "Rewind" infile stream
    while (stream_read) {
        // Grab whole row
        string s;
        if (!getline(stream_read, s))
            break;

        istringstream ss (s);
        vector<string> record;

        while(ss) {
            // Split string by comma delimiter
            string s;
            if (!getline(ss, s, ','))
                break;
            record.push_back(s);
        }

        if (line_is_header)
            header = record;
        else
            contents.push_back(record);
        line_is_header = false; // First iteration clears through the header
    }
}

void CSVFile::write_row(const map<string,string>& row_map) {
    vector<string> row_vec(header.size(), "NULL");
    map<int,string> index_map = index_from_string(row_map);
    for(auto it = index_map.begin(); it != index_map.end(); ++it) {
        row_vec[it->first] = it->second;
    }
    // for(auto&& i : row_vec) { cout << i << endl; }

    string v_string = merge_row_vector(row_vec);
    stream_write << endl << v_string;
}

map<int,string> CSVFile::index_from_string(const map<string,string>& row_map) {
    map<int,string> index_map;
    for(auto it = row_map.begin(); it != row_map.end(); ++it) {
        index_map[index_from_string(it->first)] = it->second;
    }
    return index_map;
}

int CSVFile::index_from_string(const string& s) {
    // Given column string, returns index of column
    int pos = find(header.begin(), header.end(), s) - header.begin();
    if (pos == header.size()) {
        throw out_of_range("\nColumn: " + s + " not found in header");
    }
    return pos;
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430757/c-vector-to-string
string CSVFile::merge_row_vector(const vector<string>& row_vec) {
    stringstream sstream;
    for(vector<string>::size_type ctr = 0; ctr < row_vec.size(); ++ctr) {
        string current = row_vec[ctr];
        // cout << "called : " << current << endl;
        if (ctr == 0)
            sstream << current << ",";
        else if (current == "NULL")
            sstream << ",";
        else if (ctr == row_vec.size() - 1)
            sstream << current;
        else
            sstream << current << ",";
    }
    return sstream.str();
}

vector<string> CSVFile::column_info(const string& s) {
    // Returns all data in the passed column(s)
    // Need to overload this function later
    vector<string> data;
    int index = index_from_string(s);

    for (auto&& i : contents) {
        data.push_back(i[index]);
    }

    return data;
}

CSVFile::CsvVector CSVFile::get_column(const int& index) {
    CSVFile::CsvVector column_data;
    vector<string> buffer;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < contents.size(); ++i) {
        buffer.push_back(contents[i][index]);
    }
    column_data.push_back(buffer);
    return column_data;
}

CSVFile::CsvVector CSVFile::get_column(const vector<int>& indices) {
    CSVFile::CsvVector column_data;
    for(auto&& index : indices)
    {
        vector<string> buffer;
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < contents.size(); ++i)
        {
            buffer.push_back(contents[i][index]);
        }
        column_data.push_back(buffer);
    }
    return column_data;
}

CSVFile::CsvVector CSVFile::get_column(const string& s) {
    CSVFile::CsvVector column_data;
    column_data.push_back(column_info(s));
    return column_data;
}

CSVFile::CsvVector CSVFile::get_column(const vector<string>& col_vec) {
    CSVFile::CsvVector column_data;
    for (auto&& column : col_vec) {
        column_data.push_back(column_info(column));
    }
    return column_data;
}

vector<string> CSVFile::get_row(const int& i) {
    return contents[i];
}

CSVFile::CsvVector CSVFile::get_row(const int& start, const int& end) {
    CsvVector row_range;
    for(unsigned i = start; i != end; ++i) {
        row_range.push_back(contents[i]);
    }
    return row_range;
}

ostream& print(ostream& os, const CSVFile& csv) {
    string csv_string;
    for (auto&& i : csv.contents) {
        stringstream s;
        for (auto&& j : i) {
            s << j << ' ';
        }
        s << "\n";
        csv_string += s.str();
    }
    os << csv_string;
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just briefly:

- `using namespace std` is considered as bad practice and in header file it's even worst. Now, if you remove it, it'll broke "unrelated" code in main.cpp.
- No support for another separators?
- No support for `something,"something,else",....`?
- Why are some methods implemented inside of header file? It's not a template class, so it can be all moved into .cpp file.
- No Makefile in github repository? I have to compile it by hand? (ok, not so hard but ..)
- Example main.cpp - there is nothing about what it's supposed to do.
- Output csv is not in good format. It inserted new empty line and then example data without line separator.